# Provide default integer value to Python argparse library

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, argparse

I'm trying to write a simple Daemon, which receives 2 input integer values from caller (Using Python 3.6).

In case the values are not specified, I would like argparse to choose a default integer value.

Here is my code:

```
import argparse    
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=help_text)
    parser.add_argument('daily_budget', help="Daily budget", type=int, default=10000)
    parser.add_argument('daily_watermark', help="Daily minimum budget to start running",
                    type=int, default=10001)
arguments = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When running this code **without** input parameters, I receive the following error -

```
error: the following arguments are required:daily_budget, daily_watermark
```

Can someone please help me understand what is the problem?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: try this => `required=False`

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument), the syntax for `add_argument` is:

> ArgumentParser.add_argument(name or flags...[, action][, nargs][, const][, default][, type][, choices][, required][, help][, metavar][, dest])

In the above syntax, you have the [required] parameter, which

> required - Whether or not the command-line option may be omitted (optionals only).

So, all you have to do is to add a `required=False` argument to `add_argument`:

```
parser.add_argument('daily_budget', help="Daily budget", type=int, default=10000, required=False)
```

Same goes with the other instruction.

Comment: Thanks @bogdan Doicin - I added a few more inputs on a separate answer

Comment: I am glad I could help :)

Comment: This will raise an error for the positional definition.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 missing parameters in above example -

1. In above syntax, we are missing [required] parameter as mentioned by @bogdan Doicin
2. My original parameter is positional argument (no -- option in front of the name). Positional arguments are always required!

So, in order to fix above code we need to add the following lines -

```
import argparse    
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=help_text)
    parser.add_argument('--daily_budget', help="Daily budget", type=int, default=10000, required=False)
    parser.add_argument('--daily_watermark', help="Daily minimum budget to start running",
                type=int, default=10001, required=False)
    arguments = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah, forgot the "--" part. I focused only on the requirements part of the instruction.

Comment: You don't need the required parameter with the flagged argument.  It's False by default.